# Mocking Google Maps Library in a GWT app

Tags: google-maps, gwt, mocking

We're developing a GWT app that makes heavy use of the Google Maps Library. That is, there is always (at least) one `MapWidget` attached to the DOM.

Is it somehow possible to mock out the Google Maps API? We're trying to

1. speed up the loading time of the application in development mode
2. use development mode in situations without an internet connection to prevent the error
   `java.lang.RuntimeException: The Maps API has not been loaded`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can avoid the 'The Maps API has not been loaded' error:

1) Using a simple try / catch:

```
MapWidget map;

try {
      map = new MapWidget();
      doSomething();
}
```

2) Using the GWT AjaxLoader:

```
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;

AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "2", new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }
}, null);
```